# Infinite loop while using iterator

Tags: java, iterator

```
Set key1 = map.keySet();
Iterator it1 = key1.iterator();
int cnt=0;
while (it1.hasNext()) {
  cnt++;
}
```

What are the chances that this code will result in infinite loop?

Actually it is resulting in infinite loop. My doubt is it is because I am not taking `it1.next();` , is it true?

Comment: Yup. That would indeed explain your problem.

Comment: Yes. It1 object did not iterate to next object which leads to  infinite loop.

Comment: If you want to know the number of elements in the set, simply call `key1.size()`!

Comment: Everything else is fine, but I got 2 down-votes and it's sad. is my question seriously of very low standard??

Comment: Yes, this is an extremely newbie question. Try to learn the Java basic in advance, it will save you a lot of time!

Comment: Oh OK. But each time someone will downvote I will lose some points. Is there anyway to stop downvoting??

Comment: You got the answer, so you can delete your question.

Comment: :) OK thanks :)  Upps..seems already answered questions can not be deleted.

Comment: Actually I find nothing is wrong with this question. It is a newbie question, sure, but it is well written and the question is clear.

Comment: "My doubt is it is because I am not taking it1.next(); , is it true?" Maybe just try it out.

Comment: @AndyTurner from now on I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: I think the easiest way to find out the answer would have been to try the code for yourself.

Comment: @KevinPaton yes kevin, I got my lesson :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Until you don't call `it1.next()` it will never move on to next item. Beause `it1.next()` will return the object which you have added in the list/set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't call `it1.next()` in the loop, so `it1.hasNext()` is always true. In other words, you never move to the next item.

BTW, you don't need iterator for what you want to archieve, try

```
int cnt=map.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Actually it is resulting in infinite loop. My doubt is it is because I am not taking `it1.next();` , is it true?

Yes, this is true.

However, you can find the count of a collection much easier:

```
int cnt = map.size();
```

Comment: Yes, I found the count and it was 84, so it must have stopped at 84. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically itl.hasNext() always return a boolean value based on the availability of next value to process in the collection.  Say pointer is at some position x, hasNext() returns true if there exists some element next to position x, i mean x+1 element exists,

So you must use itl.next(), which returns the current element in the collection and moves the pointer ahead by 1.  so according to our previous example, next() returns current object a position x, and moves the pointer to next poiton.

However to get the number of elements from a collection you could use

```
 collection_object.size()
```